# VB.Net CSV Out of Bounds Error

Tags: vb.net

I am having a strange problem with my code in that I am getting an out of bounds error when ever I run a "For Each line in Array" loop.
Here is the code ...

```
Dim catName As String = "Brakes"
Dim cat2Name As String = "Airline Components"
Dim cat2Location As String = catName + ".csv"
Dim cat2Data = File.ReadAllText(cat2Location)
Dim cat2Rows = Split(cat2Data, vbCrLf)
For Each line In cat2Rows
    Dim cat2Item = Split(line, ",")

    Console.WriteLine(cat2Item(2) & ",")

Next
```

When ever I run this code it displays all the information but then gives the error at the end and breaks the program.

[Here is a picture showing the problem in more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9QF3.png)

Any help with this is appreciated  :)

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` could replace the first split.  Otherwise not all rows have 3 bits of info and your code is not checking the size of cat2Item

Comment: It seems that `cat2Item` not contains any data at index 2

Comment: @Plutonix Awesome that seems to have fixed it. You wanna put it as an answer :)